# How to get root path of rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am novice to rails. I have been using LAMP for a long time. I am looking for something like {{URL::to('/')}} from Laravel.

I DO NOT want to use link_to which creates entire anchor tag as it defeats the purpose of isolating views. I want to get a value to put in href tag.

```
<a href="<%= what do i write here??? %>" class="btn btn-success">This is a link</a>
```

Comment: How about [url_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/UrlFor.html)?

Answer (score 2):

Rails has has the `root_path` and `root_url` helpers

You also seem quite confused about `link_to` it does not compromise the "isolation" of your views. Its a helper method which makes it possible to create very dynamic html without doing a lot of interpolation.

```
<%= link_to t('home'), root_path, class: 'btn btn-success' %>
```

Comment: Max, thanks for your answer but I want to keep my HTML part clean and don't want ruby to generate that for me.

Comment: I found what I needed. I am using root_url and interesting thing is it's not enabled by default.